# get substrings from string with parentheses, brackets and hyphen

Tags: php, regex

Regex is not my strongest suit and I'm having a bit of trouble with this situation.

I have the following string:

```
locale (district - town) [parish]
```

I need to extract the following information:
1 - locale
2 - district
3 - town

And I have these solutions:

1 - locale

```
preg_match("/([^(]*)\s/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

2 - district

```
preg_match("/.*\(([^-]*)\s/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

3 - town

```
preg_match("/.*\-\s([^)]*)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

And these seem to work fine.
However, the string may be presented like any of these:

```
localeA(localeB) (district - town) [parish]
locale (district - townA(townB)) [parish]
locale (district - townA-townB) [parish]
```

Locale can also include parentheses of its own.
Town can include parentheses and/or an hyphen of its own.

Which makes it difficult to extract the right information. In the 3 scenarios above I would have to extract:

localeA(localeB) + district + town

locale + district + townA(townB)

locale + district + townA-townB

I find it hard to deal with all these scenarios. Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Got speed ?](http://regex101.com/r/xS9fZ1)

Comment: @Hamza: Why a comment and why not an answer?

Comment: @anubhava I'm busy with other things and it was a quick fiddle. If I posted that as an answer, I should at least provide some explanation.

Comment: @hamza: Alright I understand, however your effort was worthy of an answer and some upvotes.

Comment: @anubhava don't worry, somebody will copy / paste it to an answer within a few minutes :)

Comment: @anubhava there is a small problem, since I use a greedy pattern in `locale` it "eats" the spaces. So maybe you can fix that and give a trimmed result :)

Comment: @dognose: in last test case OP wants: `locale + district + townA-townB)`

Comment: @anubhava I have just fixed that, the closing parentheses was a typo.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you very much for your help.
It looks great and it seems to be working. I will test it further and get back to you asap.

Answer (score 0):

If locale, district and town haven't spaces in them:

```
preg_match("/^\s*(\S+)\s*\((\S+)\s*-\s*(\S+)\)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^\s*(\S+)\s*\((\S+)\s*-\s*(\S+)\))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your rules and edge cases are, but this works for the examples provided

```
preg_match('#^(.+?) \((.+?) - (.+?)\) \[(.+)\]$#',$str,$matches);
```

Gives these results (when run for each example string in `$str`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => locale (district - town) [parish]
    [1] => locale
    [2] => district
    [3] => town
    [4] => parish
)

Array
(
    [0] => localeA(localeB) (district - town) [parish]
    [1] => localeA(localeB)
    [2] => district
    [3] => town
    [4] => parish
)

Array
(
    [0] => locale (district - townA(townB)) [parish]
    [1] => locale
    [2] => district
    [3] => townA(townB)
    [4] => parish
)

Array
(
    [0] => locale (district - townA-townB) [parish]
    [1] => locale
    [2] => district
    [3] => townA-townB
    [4] => parish
)
```